# Delay the beginning of an animation

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to end this animation after a couple of seconds. I'll give you a few secs to study my markup.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       //when mouse enters .box .cover will animate to go to 150px
        $('.box').mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.cover').stop().animate({
                top: '150px'
             })
        //when mouse leaves .box - .cover will set back to 300px
       .mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.cover').stop().animate({
                top: '300px',
                duration: 300        
            })
          });
        });



});
```

What I want to do is after my mouse leaves `.cover` I want to wait a few seconds for `.cover` to go to top:300px.

How can I achieve this? Any possible solutions? Can you also explain shortly what I was missing and what I am doing wrong? I want to learn what I did wrong or what I missed.

Thanks Stack Overflow!

Comment: Animation by it's nature will end the animation after it reaches the parameter, why do you want to delay?

Comment: Once my mouse leaves .cover it instantly animates to top:300px I want to wait a few seconds for it to animate to 300px.

Comment: I'm going to retitle this question from "How to end an animation after a couple of seconds" to "Delay the beginning of an animation" because your original title is very misguiding.

Comment: I would retitle it to " Delay the end of an animation " because that is what I want to achieve. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: No, the first animation completes i.e. mouseenter and only when mouseleave occurs do you want to delay the START of that animation. So saying the "end of animation" is misguiding.

Comment: Hmm.. You are right, because there are two animations not one. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Delay it](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

edit:
This:

```
$(this).parent().find('.cover').stop().animate({
                top: '300px',
                duration: 300        
            })
```

change for:

```
$(this).parent().find('.cover').stop().delay(4000).animate({
                top: '300px',
                duration: 300        
            })
```

Comment: That's the most lazy answer every.

Comment: This sort of helps and is one possible solution but I want to know how to implement it correctly. Thanks though.

Comment: So now, it's not the laziest.